# How can I initialize an ArrayList with all zeroes in Java?

Tags: java, collections

It looks like `arraylist` is not doing its job for presizing:

```
// presizing 

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(60);
```

Afterwards when I try to access it:

```
list.get(5)
```

Instead of returning 0 it throws *IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 0*.

Is there a way to initialize all elements to 0 of an exact size like what C++ does?

Comment: The Javadoc of that constructor specifies that it creates an "empty list". It is doing its job.

Answer (score 532, accepted):

The integer passed to the constructor represents its **initial capacity**, i.e., the number of elements it can hold before it needs to resize its internal array (and has nothing to do with the initial number of elements in the list).

To initialize an list with 60 zeros you do:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(60, 0));
```

---

If you want to create a list with 60 *different* objects, you could use the Stream API with a `Supplier` as follows:

```
List<Person> persons = Stream.generate(Person::new)
                             .limit(60)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That is much better than my solution (even my updated one that actually works hehehe). I would recommend not making a new `ArrayList` out of it though, and instead simply program to `List`. That's a decision left to the OP, of course.

Comment: The list returned by `nCopies` is immutable, so creating a new `ArrayList` is probably a good idea.

Comment: Beware that when using the `nCopies` with a complex object the collection is not instantiated with 60 different objects, but 60 times with the same object. So only use this for primitives.

Comment: @membersound, I can think of many scenarios where `nCopies` is useful with reference types: Immutable objects such as strings, null-object patterns, enum constants, ... Anyway, I updated the answer with a solution for creating 60 different objects.

Comment: @aioobe I know there are many scenarios where ncopies is useful. I just wanted to add this, as I tried ncopies with mutable objects and was surprised it did not work as I'd expect. Just in case anyone tries the same task. thanks for the update though!

Answer (score 13):

```
// apparently this is broken. Whoops for me!
java.util.Collections.fill(list,new Integer(0));

// this is better
Integer[] data = new Integer[60];
Arrays.fill(data,new Integer(0));
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(data);
```

Comment: This only fills a list with existing entries. It won't initialize it with elements as desired.

Comment: This won't fill the list with 60 zeros.

Comment: Even if it would it'd create 60 objects where it doesn't have to create any.

Comment: it works after ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(60);

Comment: @White, aioobe, Interesting. I wasn't aware of this. I'll fix.

Comment: @Frost: you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` with `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(60); Collections.fill(list, new Integer(0)); list.get(5);`

Comment: @Frost, I admit that it doesn't, I tried it. But I have a fix forthcoming.

Comment: @aioobe right - I had meant to do that from the get go :) fixed!

Comment: `Arrays.asList` produces a `List` that doesn't allow adding or removing, so it's not quite the same as what the OP wants. It would work if all you need to do is `set`, but you might be better of just using an array in that case.

Answer (score 9):

Java 8 implementation *(List initialized with `60` zeroes)*:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(new int[60])
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- `new int[N]` - creates an array filled with zeroes & length N
- `boxed()` - each element boxed to an Integer
- `collect(Collectors.toList())` - collects elements of stream

Answer (score 7):

The 60 you're passing is just the initial capacity for internal storage. It's a hint on how big you think it might be, yet of course it's not limited by that. If you need to preset values you'll have to set them yourself, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    list.add(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not like that. ArrayList just uses array as internal respentation. If you add more then 60 elements then underlaying array will be exapanded. How ever you can add as much elements to this array as much RAM you have.