# how to initialize arraylist of arraylist

Tags: java, data-structures

Following line will initialize arraylist with 9 elements with value true.

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> timeTable = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Collections.nCopies(9, true));
```

But how can i initialize arraylist  of arraylist?

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> timeTable = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>(Collections.nCopies(9, true));
```

It should mean that outer arraylist has 9 inner arraylist and each inner arraylist has 9 elements with true value.

Similar to [How can I initialize an ArrayList with all zeroes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java) 
But not exactly same...

Scenario is that i need to maintain a monthly list of daily timetables. Now daily timetable will have only 9 entries, so immutable is fine. But monthly list needs to be appended each month. So it can't be an arraylist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this line form java docs: "Returns an immutable list consisting of n copies of the specified object"

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> timeTable = new ArrayList<Boolean>(Collections.nCopies(9, true));

public ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> timeTableLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>>(Collections.nCopies(9, timeTable));
```

Comment: Scenario is that i need to maintain a monthly list of daily timetables. Now daily timetable will have only 9 entries, so immutable is fine. But monthly list needs to be appended each month. So it can't be an arraylist.

Comment: So you're saying that timeTableList should be mutable. Than you need to use a for loop

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it is recommended to use interface types wherever possible. That would make your

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> -> List<List<Boolean>>.
```

Then, the initialization statement would become

```
public List<List<Boolean>> timeTable = Collections.nCopies(9, (Collections.nCopies(9, true)));
```

Comment: No guarantee that nCopies returns an ArrayList if that was a requirement.

Comment: Completely agree, but I doubted if ArrayList was really a requirement and List wouldn't suffice here.

Comment: Scenario is that i need to maintain a monthly list of daily timetables. Now daily timetable will have only 9 entries, so immutable is fine. But monthly list needs to be appended each month. So it can't be an arraylist.