# Adding null values to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Can I add `null` values to an `ArrayList` even if it has a generic type parameter?

Eg.

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
itemList.add(null);
```

If so, will

```
itemsList.size();
```

return 1 or 0?

If I can add `null` values to an `ArrayList`, can I loop through only the indexes that contain items like this?

```
for(Item i : itemList) {
   //code here
}
```

Or would the for each loop also loop through the null values in the list?

Comment: Yes, 1, no, yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java Similar to this use null instead of 0

Comment: Note that IntelliJ hides those nulls, which can be disabled - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430633/intellij-idea-debugger-does-not-show-null-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes, you can always use `null` instead of an object. Just be careful because some methods might throw error.

It would be 1.

Also `null`s would be factored in in the for loop, but you could use

```
for (Item i : itemList) {
    if (i != null) {
       //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, `List.of(...)` will throw if the supplied value is null. This is dumb -- just putting it out there. It's perfectly legit to have a null value in a list!

Comment: `List.of(...)` will throw exception however `Stream.of(null, "a").toList()` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoshM. Weirdly enough, `Collections.singletonList()` does allow `null`, which means that the `of` method is even more "off". Anyway, if you need to create a list of one element that may be `null` then `singletonList` may help.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes that's ridiculous. Thanks for ruining my morning. :-D

Answer (score 35):

You can add nulls to the `ArrayList`, and you will have to check for nulls in the loop:

```
for(Item i : itemList) {
   if (i != null) {

   }
}
```

`itemsList.size();` would take the `null` into account.

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 list.add(null);
 list.add (5);
 System.out.println (list.size());
 for (Integer value : list) {
   if (value == null)
       System.out.println ("null value");
   else 
       System.out.println (value);
 }
```

Output :

```
2
null value
5
```

Comment: Thank you, I am guessing the .size() method also takes the null values into account.

Answer (score 3):

You could create Util class:

```
public final class CollectionHelpers {
    public static <T> boolean addNullSafe(List<T> list, T element) {
        if (list == null || element == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return list.add(element);
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
Element element = getElementFromSomeWhere(someParameter);
List<Element> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
CollectionHelpers.addNullSafe(list, element);
```

Comment: This will never add anything to the list if the list is empty to begin with.