# IntelliJ IDEA Debugger does not show null element in a list

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I have a list in which the first element is `null`. IntelliJ debugger correctly shows the list size as 5, but it shows only 1,2,3,4 elements. It would be nice to see that element with the index 0 is `null` (it took me some time to figure out my problems while debugging because it did not show that). Is it possible to force IntelliJ to show this?

Here is a screenshot, where the size is 5 and the elements shown are only 1-4 because the first element is `null`:

[image]

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Null array elements are hidden by default, you can disable it here:

[image: hide null]

Comment: WT* .. Version 16.1.3 doesn't even show the message "Not showing null elements" in the debugger, which is present in newer versions. Why would this be default anyway!?

Comment: Agree with @nyxz - why on earth is this the default? Just wasted a heap of time diagnosing an issue due to this misleading and unexpected behaviour, which definitely violates the principle of least-surprise.

Comment: @MattCraig please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221059

Comment: Why it should be enabled by default?

Comment: i love how the intellij team keep adding stupid features to make life difficult for everyone