# How to initialise an arrayList for fixed size and assign it to nil

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I initialise an arrayList for fixed size and assign it to nil?
I have code as below in Swift/IoS.
What is the equivalent in Java for below code in Java?

```
var studentsList:[Result?] = [Result?](repeating: nil, count: 5) //assign to nil
studentsList[2] = newStudent //assign at different level Eg:2
studentsList = studentsList.filter { $0 != nil } //filter all the nil objects
```

I need an array for fixed length.
I am able to add the elements in the order, but I need the ability to add the element at any of the initialised levels.
For example, if I fix the size of array as 5, I should be able to assign object to arrList[2] even though arrList[0] and arrList[1] are still nil

Comment: In English, what are you trying to do here, and more importantly -- why?

Comment: What do you mean "assign it to nil"? You want to fill the array with a certain number of `null`s?

Comment: I think you mean you want an array with a fixed size not an ArrayList

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter nil is null in swift

Comment: @CupofJava: I figured as much, but the whole thing still smells of being an XY Problem, which is why the *why* is so important.

Comment: I think this pretty much a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java but I'm hesitant to call it since it's not clear what the question is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I initialize an ArrayList with all zeroes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java)

Comment: I need an array for fixed length. I am able to add the elements in the order but what i need is ability to add the element at any of the initialised levels. For example, if I fix the size of array as 5, I should be able to assign object to arrList[2] even though arrList[0] and arrList[1] are still nil. The code i have posted is exactly how it works in Swift/iOS

Comment: And you can do that... `arrList[2] = new Student()`

Comment: I tried below and it gives me java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException. StudentList.add(1, newStudent);

Comment: @dacscan3669 - You're probably accessing an array element outside the declared index

Comment: Below is the current code which throws OutofBoundsException. private ArrayList<SchoolItem> StudentList = new ArrayList<>(5); StudentList.add(1, newStudent);

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(Collections.nCopies(5, null));
studentList.set(2, newStudent)
//studentList = studentList.stream().filter(e -> e != null)
```

Since it seems you're using Android, and streams won't work, use the following:

```
ArrayList<Student> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Student s : studentList) 
    if(student !=null) 
       studentList.add(student)
```

Comment: The last command shows an error. cannot resolve method 'stream' hovering on stream and also 'Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level' for (e -> e != null)

Comment: @dacscan3669 I assume you're programming for Android then. Streams were added in Java 8, so they aren't available in all android versions

Comment: @dacscan3669 Instead, you'll have to use a loop `for(Student s : studentList) if(student !=null) tempList.add(student)`

Comment: @dacscan3669 If my answer helped you out, I'd appreciate if you could accept it (by pressing the green check above). Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Give what you said in the comments, you're probably looking for:

```
StudentList[] studentarray = new StudentList[5];
studentarray[2]= studentObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make an array of an Object class, it is all null.

```
Student[] students = new Student[5];
```

And you can assign an index, which keeps the rest as null.

```
students[2] = new Student();
```

An array is fixed size and cannot be added to.

If you want a stream out of an array, you can do that as well

```
Arrays.stream(students).filter( Objects::nonNull )
```

Comment: The last command shows an error. cannot resolve method 'stream' hovering on stream and also  'Method references are not supported at this language level' for Objects::nonNull

Comment: The last command does not work on Android and hence had to go for alternate solution. The first 2 commands are fine.

Comment: Java 8 features are being added. https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html Your question was not tagged with android.

Comment: You could also use RxJava, which is an interesting library to wrap Android code with

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(new Student[fixedSize]);
```

This is a List, not an ArrayList.  But you can modify each element.  If you add an element to `students`, exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by using the below code based on suggestions posted.

```
Student[] studentList = new SchoolItem[5];

ArrayList<Student> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();

compareList[2] = new Student();

for( Student s : compareList) {
       if(s !=null)
       sortedList.add(s); }
```