# How to add default values to ArrayList - solving: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Say I have something like this:

```
public void handle(ArrayList<Object> tasks) {

    ArrayList<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        results.set(i, tasks.get(i);
    }
}
```

if I do the above I will get an error:

> Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0

so the temporary/dumb solution I have is to do:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
      results.add(null);
      results.set(i, tasks.get(i);
  }
```

but that is awful lol...how do we do this right with Java?

Comment: 1 liner `ArrayList<Object> results = new ArrayList<>(tasks);`

Comment: that's cool, but that's duplicating a lot of object references that I am going to end up discarding, I'd rather just put a bunch of nulls in there?

Comment: also, what if tasks has 100K items, seems expensive

Comment: IMO, having a list with 100K, is itself expensive.

Comment: Thaz true, pretty rare case, then again we have linked-lists doing crazy optimization since traversing big arrays recursively/compound is hard, if this was part of some recursive thing it could get nasty, it's all about that big-O

Comment: @rakim Maybe List isn't optimal data structure for you, but there's little information to tell.

Comment: Yeah it just seems unnecessary to have to copy all the data from one array to a new one to initialize properly, I think you'd agree. With JS you wouldn't have to do anything like this. You'd just be like `const z = []; z[3] = "salamander"`.

Comment: So this works, not sure if it's that much better tho `List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>(Collections.nCopies(tasks.size(), 0));`

Comment: just `add` instead of `set` (`set` is for replacing an item under certain index, and `add` will put item at the end of the list which in this case is at index `i`). You may consider using `Map<Integer, Object>` and `put`. Another solution is to use java array `Object[] array = new Object[tasks.size()]` - if you know exact size of the array before, this one will be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (Object task:tasks) {
        if(task==null) {
        results.add(task)
       }      
    }
```

Comment: what about `List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>(Collections.nCopies(tasks.size(), 0));`

Comment: Why you need add 0 in to results ??? Method you post mean : You want add tasks.size() with 0 value. It mean : Example : tasks you contain 5 element, after   method run  result is : 0,0,0,0,0 . task.size() is capacity and 0 is value you want add.

Comment: You can read it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`set()` is used for replacing a previously added element, hence why you got an error in your first approach. And in your second approach why not just use `results.add(tasks.get(i))` instead of first adding a `null` object and replacing it with `set()`