# Java: Initialize an array of 0.0 or 1 or "A" with size n*1 or size n*m

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am still new to Java.

I am wondering if there is a quick way to initialize a Java Array with size (`n*1` or `n*m`) and values (`0.0, or 1, or "A"`)provided.

In this post,
[Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line), intilizing Java array is given as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
```

or

```
List<String> list = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

or

```
List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");
```

However, none of them is what I want.

I am wondering if it is possible to initialize an Java array of size `n*1` or `n*m` with `0.0` (double array), or `1` (integer array), or `"A"` (string array).

These initialization will be one/two line code in matlab/python, e.g. In python, `ZerosVector = numpy.zeros((n,1))` will return a `n*1` vector with zeros. In matlab  `CellMatrix = cell(10,20); CellMatrix(:) ="A"` will return a cell matrix with string "A".

Any equivalent package/implementation in Java for such fast initialization without using loop?

Comment: Do you want an Array (`String[]`) or a List (`List<String>`)?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS, sorry, I still do not quite know the difference. But the size is known beforehand, e.g. `n*1`. If  `String[]` indicate fixed size, then I mean Array. Any example to initialize an array of double with value 0.0, an array of integer with value 1, and an array of string with "A", size are all `n*m`?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600668/how-can-i-initialize-an-arraylist-with-all-zeroes-in-java) other question might shed some light for `ArrayLists`. For `arrays` you could look into [Arrays.fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(double[],%20double))

Comment: For `double` the default value is btw. already `0.0`. So to create a double array of length n*m filled with 0.0 all you need is really `new double[n*m]`.

Comment: @StaticBeagle, the link is quite helpful. I did not see this post before the post as I was searching `Array` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: You may also take a look at [what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426843/what-is-the-default-initialization-of-an-array-in-java/3426854)

Comment: Why do the tags include python and matlib if this is a question about java? Language-spamming is not appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it into a one-liner, you can make a simple method, that does it.
You can pass the size and value and return the new **ArrayList**:

```
static ArrayList<String> populateArrayList(int size, String defaultValue) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        list.add(defaultValue);
    return list;
}
```

If you wish to use static list - **array**, then similar code can be applied:

```
static String[] populateArray(int size, String defaultValue) {
    String[] array = new String[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = defaultValue;
    return array;
}
```

And then to use, just **call the method** and assign its returned value to a new list:

```
ArrayList<String> data1 = populateArrayList(100, "Doggo");
String[] data2 = populateArray(100, "Moo-moo");
```

#### Default values

As stated in comments, variables of different data types have their default values that are used in arrays, object params etc.

- for numerics it is 0,
- for boolean - true,
- for String and other type it is null

More about default values [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)